# Laravel 5 memcached not found while properly installed

Tags: php, laravel-5, memcached

I have PHP 5.4 on a litespeed web server. PHP has been compiled properly with memcached module and we also installed properly memcached library.

In fact the problem suddenly happened without any change at all (server side) when I run the artisan command, I am getting this error:

```
PHP Fatal error: Class 'Memcached' not found in /laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cache/MemcachedConnector.php on line 52

[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]
Class 'Memcached' not found
```

I googled the issue but was unable to find a solution. I am using Laravel 5.0.

I edited the app/Http/Routes.php and returned new Memcached at the top of the file and the php object was returned so it means memcached is properly installed on the server...

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. My problem was when I was running the artisan command, the artisan was using another version of PHP (different than the Litespeed one) and this PHP was not compiled with memcached.

Comment: how did you fix it then?