# laravel class memcached not found

Tags: php, laravel, ubuntu, memcached, entrust

First of all , I have looked at all of these :

[#1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27991908/php-5-4-laravel-class-memcached-not-found) , [#2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31660915/laravel-5-memcached-not-found-while-properly-installed) , [#3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34196482/class-memcached-not-found-in-laravel)

and none of them is my case nor has really a soloution.

The problem is that I am developing a website by laravel 5.3.18 and here is the PHP info running on my server:

```
PHP 7.0.9-2 (cli) ( NTS )                                                    
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group                                        
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies                
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.9-2, Copyright (c) 1999-2016, by Zend Technologies
```

And also here is my server OS info if you need to take a look at:

```
No LSB modules are available.                          
Distributor ID: Debian                                 
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux stable-updates (sid)  
Release:        stable-updates                         
Codename:       sid
```

I need to change CACHE_DRIVER to memcached in order to use [this package](https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust)(according to what they say in the GitHub issues about fixing the found bug).

Here is where all my problems started.

I have thses memcahed packages installed on my server(listed by dpkg --list):

[image]

I see everyone is talking avout installing php5-memcached but shockingly when I try to install php5-memcached I get this:

[image]

**and tha's after running** `sudo apt-get update`!

I even get this after entering `sudo service memcached status`:
[image]

After all of these when I change the CACHE_DRIVER to memcached, it keeps on showing this error:

[image]

**While I am still struggling with this, Any ideas on this guys? I would be appreciative!**

Comment: Try installing PHP7 compatible memcached package. Add this repo `ppa:ondrej/php` and then install `php-memcached` package.

Comment: If you're already running php 7, you shouldn't need to add any repositories. Try installing php7.0-memcached instead.

Comment: 'Unable to locate package php7-memcached'

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that the memcached.ini is being copied to the PHP5 module config directory.

Try this:

```
ln -s /etc/php/mods-available/memcached.ini /etc/php/7.0/fpm/conf.d/20-memcached.ini
```

You might copy msgpack.ini too:

```
ln -s /etc/php/mods-available/msgpack.ini /etc/php/7.0/fpm/conf.d/20-msgpack.ini
```

Answer (score 1):

Class `Memcached` is also used by php 7 ([PHP 7 with memcached](https://serversforhackers.com/video/installing-php-7-with-memcached))

Check this out - http://pecl.php.net/package/memcached

You may need to also install `libmemcached` see this - https://launchpad.net/libmemcached/+download

Or see the similar issue on - [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27991908/php-5-4-laravel-class-memcached-not-found)